# Trying to use WMI to display the MTU values for the network adapters on a system

Tags: vbscript, wmi, mtu

I have this subroutine that is just displaying blank lines.

```
'*************************************************************************
' Check MTU
'*************************************************************************
Sub CheckMTU()
   WScript.Echo("Check if MTU Size is set to 1300")
   WScript.Echo("------------------------------------")
   Set colNetwork = objWMISrvc.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")
   For Each objItem in colNetwork
      WScript.Echo(objItem.MTU & vbCrLf)
   Next
End Sub
```

I want to test to see if the network adapters have a MTU value of 1300. This will be run on multiple machines and the issue I have is the name of network adapters in the registry are always different. It would be nice if my implementation worked...

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I changed the subroutine to this, but it isn't working.

```
'*************************************************************************
' Check MTU
'*************************************************************************
Sub CheckMTU()
   Dim intResult
   WScript.Echo("Verify MTU Size is 1300. Changes MTU Size to 1300 ")
   WScript.Echo("------------------------------------")
   Set colNetwork = objWMISrvc.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE IPEnabled = True") 'WHERE IPEnabled = True
   For Each objItem in colNetwork
      WScript.Echo objItem
      intResult = objItem.SetMTU(1300)
      WScript.Echo intResult
   Next
   If intResult = 0 or intResult = 1 Then
      WScript.Echo("Network Adapter MTU Value is set to 1300. Test PASSED" & vbCrLf)
   Else
      WScript.Echo("Network Adapter MTU Value can't be set to 1300. Test FAILED" & vbCrLf)
   End If
End Sub
```

It isn't even printing out the intResult or objItem. It almost feels as if it isn't getting anything from colNetwork.

Any suggestions? Should I make a new post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure why there's no MTU value.. BUT you can always set the MTU value calling the **SetMTU** method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393463(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is what I may do...instead of checking the servers network adapter to see if it is set...I may just set it in the script.

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect this new change. Something is strange about it though...

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
WScript.Echo(objItem.MTU & vbCrLf)
```

To:

```
WScript.Echo objItem.MTU
```

Comment: I too get NULL, but my value IS NULL; are you sure your network adapter MTU value isn't NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I think is because this value is used to overwrite the default value.

```
"Overrides the default Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) for a network interface."
```

If it's null, the default value is used, if it's not, it overwrites the default value.
You can view the default MTU value reported by the driver with the following netsh command:

```
netsh interface ip show subinterfaces
```